# How to transmitt parameters as part of HTTP request in jquery data table to spring boot controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, datatables

I am new to web development. I need to transmit parameters in HTTP request in from jquery datatable ajax call to spring boot controller.

Present i am passing parameters in URL but it is a security issue. So i am trying to transmit in HTTP request.

This is my Present jquery code

`````
$("button#search").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var age = $("#age").val();
    var url = "/searchCustomer/search?name="+name+"&age="+age;
    $('#customerTable').DataTable({
    "type": "GET",
    "ajax": url,
    "cache": false,
    "bDestroy":true,
    "aLengthMenu": [20, 50, 70, 100],
    "columns":[
    {"data": "customerid" },
    {"data": "name"},
    {"data": "mobilenumber"},
    {"data": "status"},
    ],
    "language": {
    "lengthMenu": "| View _MENU_ records per page",
    "zeroRecords": "No matching records found",
    "infoEmpty": "No records available",
    "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
    },
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    });
});````

Java code:

````@RequestMapping(value = "/searchCustomer/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)   
    public @ResponseBody JSONObject getCustomers(@RequestParam(required = false) String name,@RequestParam(required = false) String age, Model model) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> list1 = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    JSONObject ajson = new JSONObject();
    //Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    //my logic here
    //list1.add(map);
    ajson.put("data", list1);
    retrun json;
    }````

I am excepting get parameters from HTTP request in Controller.
`````

Comment: This: _Present i am passing parameters in URL but it is a security issue. So i am trying to transmit in HTTP request._ Change the DataTable `type` to `POST` to accomplish this. Your Java needs additional consideration, but you've not provided enough detail.

Comment: @Randy Casburn check my url `var url = "/searchCustomer/search?name="+name+"&age="+age;`. present parameters passing in URL.

Comment: You would need to remove those query params from the URL and pass them in as the POST body of your request using POST. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

Comment: @Randy Casburn sir i am new to this type of problems can you provide me sample code please. and present that url calling inside `datatable`.

Answer (score 0):

Per your request in comments, here is code that will accomplish your goal. Note the use of the `data` parameter to `DataTables()`.

```js
$("button#search").click(function() {
  $('#customerTable').DataTable({
    ajax: "/searchCustomer/search",
    data: {
      name: $("#name").val(),
      age: $("#age").val()
    }
    cache: false,
    bDestroy: true,
    aLengthMenu: [20, 50, 70, 100],
    columns: [{
        data: "customerid"
      },
      {
        data: "name"
      },
      {
        data: "mobilenumber"
      },
      {
        data: "status"
      },
    ],
    language: {
      lengthMenu: "| View _MENU_ records per page",
      zeroRecords: "No matching records found",
      infoEmpty: "No records available",
      infoFiltered: "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
    },
    pagingType: "full_numbers",
  });
});
```

In terms of your Java, you have not provided enough detail, but the solution is simple following the Spring.io guide for building RESTful services with Spring. Your controller code would look something like this:

```
@PostMapping("/search")
  Customer search(@RequestBody SearchParams searchParams ) {
    return repository.findOne(searchParams);
  }
```